# Is there any way to prevent memory leak without asking developers to pay extra attention to it in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Currently, we have several way to prevent memory leak such as

1. proxy(shared_ptr, auto_ptr) and
2. book keeping method,
3. garbage collection(java)

But the former one needs much overhead from developers and the later one cause much resource overhead.

Is there any other way that is resource efficient and free developers from this problem?

Comment: If there was a one-size-fits-all solution to get rid of it for no price, wouldn't you think it would be advertised in every beginners c++ book?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: RAII certainly *should* be advertised in every beginner's book. Sadly, I suspect many don't teach it early enough.

Comment: 0. Stack variables. Can't leak. You have to try hard for that. See remarks on RAII.

Comment: In 1. proxy, the first one in your list should be `unique_ptr`. It is easier to use (properly) than `shared_ptr`. `auto_ptr` is banned keyword ;).

Comment: Java Garbage Collection doesn't prevent all memory leaks. You can still easily leave objects in global collections which will never be freed. This is still a memory leak, albeit, not a lost pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I wouldn't disagree, it is useful for many other things too (although I personally tend to call it SBRM). But it won't magically fix all problems, and it needs the developer to be quite disciplined, probably more than in other styles. I wouldn't call that "[...] and free developers from this [...]"

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to prevent memory leak without asking developers to pay extra attention to it in C++?

Use minimal dynamic allocations, **infact only when strictly necessary**.
If you are using Dynamic allocations you will have to obey the price it comes with and that is handling it correctly. The best way to do so is using **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)** in C++, Note that writing an RAII code is not trivial but with practice it one gets used to thinking in RAII way.

Comment: +1 for *"Use minimal dynamic allocations, **infact only when strictly necessary**."*

Comment: I disagree on one point : writing RAII is trivial. At least when compared to anything else that manages memory in C++. I think notably about the trap of passing `shared_ptr` by anything else than ref-to-const.

Comment: Keep in mind you can easily do scope-bound resource management (SBRM, a better name for RAII) with a scope-exit kind of utility, so you don't even need to write lots of small utility classes.

Comment: @GMan: actually, it was pointed to me that SBRM is slightly different than RAII, since RAII also accommodate variables leaving the scope (for example, `func(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Obj>>& m)` :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Hm, expand on that? I didn't catch it. :S

Comment: @GMan: SBRM seem to imply that the lifetime of the variable is bound to a particular scope (`scoped_ptr` is a fine example). However with `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` the allocated resource may *not* be bound to a particular scope.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Ah, gotcha. Damn...now I'm torn on the term. Oh well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well good coding practising become good programming **habits** and then there is very little "attention" required in order to utilise them. I would suggest using RAII wrapper objects such as std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr, alongside clear guidelines on when and where your should use dynamic allocation.
A good place to start is that if you see anyone typing the word `delete` then it should be a flag that you need to be extra careful.

This brings me to my second point: Don't use dynamic allocation (unless absolutely necessary), use automatically destroyed scope-controlled objects as much as possible. NEVER `new` an RAII object, and this will force you to think about how the object that the RAII owner wraps should be handled if the scope changes.

For example:

```
std::auto_ptr<Foo> ptr2Foo( new Foo() );
...
...
if(ptr2Foo->isValidNow())
    passToOwningObject(otherObject, ptr2Foo);
//now when scope ends the newed Foo will be destroyed or owned
//by an appropriate object.
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr2Foo( new Foo() );
...
...
if(ptr2Foo->isValidNow())
    passToOwningObject(otherObject, std::move(ptr2Foo));
//now when scope ends the newed Foo will be destroyed or owned
//by an appropriate object.
```

And run code anaylsis (MSVC, Valgrind, Coverity etc...) regularly, and don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: You need to `std::move` a `unique_ptr` to pass its ownership.

Comment: @Xeo - opps. I haven't used them yet (in VC9)... autos are what I actually use, so changed to that.

Answer (score 0):

I've always felt using references, return and pass by reference, and const correctness as exactly as possible can take care of much of it.  You can't delete a reference, so you're not expected to.  You can't delete a const pointer, so you're not expected to.  Then on those RARE occasions a coder is passed a non const pointer they'll take notice.

Pay real attention to the idea of ownership of heap allocated objects and reveal/expose them grudgingly if at all.

Also, write more complete interfaces to give clues, for example:

```
class DataWrapper
{
public:
    const BYTE* PeekAtData() const;        
    BYTE* RemoveData();
....
};
```

Comment: You can delete a pointer-to-const perfectly fine, see [this](http://ideone.com/PdS99).

Comment: I should've said "mess with", which is drifting off topic really.  But so much code I've seen has had everything bunged as bare pointers, and memory leaks/corruption stem from some of the same bad habits!  Damn, I'm getting angry...  : )